# Android add chips anywhere inside EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-chips

I would like to do something similar to this:

[image: example]

In other words, these "tags" are optional and can be placed anywhere inside a text.

These tags are used to indicate how the text after it will be treated when the user submits it to the server.

Comment: Seems like you're asking for a third party libraries. Have you tried to search it first? I'm sure there are already a couple of them out there.

Comment: yes I did find some chips libs, but all of them work the same. Meaning you cannot add custom text inside the edit text, you can only add the chips.

Comment: There actually are many libraries when you search Android Chips Edittext. Please describe what you've tried and any errors or problems you are having

Comment: as I said, I found limitations, not errors. None of them allowed me to add custom text in between tags if I wanted to.

Comment: consider using this , its the best and good one 
https://github.com/DoodleScheduling/android-material-chips

Comment: thanks Abdul, I'll try that one!

Comment: @user3900456 always show your research when asking a question. It helps potential answerers to build on it.

Comment: that lib doesn't seem to have this functionality I need. Maybe I should just try a different approach. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3900456 hi did u implement this functionality ?